# How to fire KeyPreview Event when form has a TActionMainMenuBar

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

When I set the property KeyPreview = TRUE on my main form (MDI Parent) the OnKeyDown, OnKeyUp or OnKeyPress events don't get fired.
When pressing keys, I can navigate the main menu (TActionMenuBar). It seems the menu bar has the control over the key events.

How can I fire an event, when the user is pressing a key (e.g. the VK_RETURN key)?

I am using Delphi 2009

Comment: This will not be easy because menus are running in their own message loop and your form is blocked until the menu is closed. What exactly are you trying to do? When user presses VK_RETURN a menu item is selected, menu is closed and you can handle menu item's OnClick or the linked action's OnExecute event.

Comment: When I press the VK_Return key, I want to open a child form. For quick access (instead of pressing a button in my toolbar).

Comment: When you press VK_RETURN on a specific menu item, I presume? In that case you should use the menu item's OnClick event. Or, if your menu item is linked with an action, use the action's OnExecute event. The code is executed when the menu item is selected, regardless whether by mouse or keyboard.

Comment: When I press the VK_RETURN key, I don't want to interact with the menu. When there is no child open in the MDI Main Form, pressing the VK_RETURN key should just open my child window.

Comment: The trouble is, when the menu is active, you have to interact with it. (More precisely, you can't interact with anything else in your app.)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I see that you want to do a certain action (eg. open a form) when a certain key is pressed.

For this, you can assign your shortcut key to an `TAction` and write the appropriate code in the `TAction.OnExecute`

Steps:

1. Drop a `TActionManager` (or `TActionList`)
2. Double click on it (the `TActionManager`'s editor appear). Press 'New Action' button.
3. Set the `ShortCut` property to the desired value.
4. Write the appropriate code in `OnExecute` event.

Note that on step 3. (perhaps) you (and most probably your users) will have trouble assigning the `Enter` key to something so uncommon like opening a form. 'Enter' has a very defined meaning in Windows.

I'd suggest to assign a functional key (F2-F9 usually) and/or Ctrl+*[the first letter of your form's name]*

HTH

Comment: Is it possible to set the ENTER key for as ShortCut? I cannot see it in the TAction.ShortCut list. FYI: In our application we use the ENTER key a lot.

Comment: Yes. Just write it. :-) 
Go to the `Shortcut` property and type 'Enter' (without the quotes). Press [Enter] (the key). 

In order to test it, go to `OnExecute` event and write some testing code like `ShowMessage('Boo!');` or similar. You will see that code being executed.

The reason for which the 'Enter' isn't included in that list is that, as I said, its usage is discouraged for custom actions. This isn't (un)fortunately my choice or Delphi's but a Windows convention.

But if it fits for your application, go ahead, even if sometimes Windows will hook it. Test and if it works...

Comment: hm ... I cannot set the ENTER key in the ShortCut property in D2009. I get the error "Inalid Property Value". But it works in D7?

Comment: Don't know for D7 Just typing `Enter` in D2010 works. And imho it should work also in D2009 `TextToShortCut` (the underlying engine for this) is a rather old Delphi function. Try type, for example, `A+Ctrl` inside of `ShortCut` property. It works? (The IDE should accept it and change it to Ctrl+A)